# Finding the closed form of a multiplicative function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer and $n>0$. Define function $g$ by $g(1)=1$ and $g(n) = 2^{m}$, where $m$ is the number of distinct prime numbers in the prime factorization of $n$. I've already proven that $g$ is multiplicative.

Now define $f$ as follows:

$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n,d>0}g(d)$$.

If $p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{m}^{a_{m}}$ is the prime factorization of $n$, find a formula for $f$ in terms of this prime factorization. **The question explicitly says that $f$ is multiplicative.** Also, each of $p_{1}^{a_{1}}, p_{2}^{a_{2}}, \cdots , p_{m}^{a_{m}}$ are pairwise relatively prime, so we use this fact in my attempt.

$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n,d>0}g(d) = f(n)$$

$$= f(p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{m}^{a_{m}})$$

$$= f(p_{1}^{a_{1}})f(p_{2}^{a_{2}})\cdots f(p_{m}^{a_{m}})$$

$$= \sum_{d|p_{1}^{a_{1}}}g(d)\sum_{d|p_{2}^{a_{2}}}g(d)\cdots\sum_{d|p_{m}^{a_{m}}}g(d)$$

$$= (1+a_{1}\cdot2^{1})(1+a_{2}\cdot2^{1})\cdots(1+a_{m}\cdot2^{1})$$

But i don't know how I would simplify this, nor am I really writing $f$ in terms of the prime factorization of $n$. What is a better way of going about this?

Comment: why did you assume that $f$ is multiplicative I think it can be proven to be multiplicative

Comment: The question says "Note that $f$ is multiplicative by part (a) (which was proving $g$ was multiplicative) and Theorem 3.1 (in our book)". So we can assume it as it is easy to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer that I was getting was correct (as per the answer in the back of the book, which I didn't know was there). We can safely assume $f$ is multiplicative.

$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n,d>0}g(d)$$

$$= f(p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{m}^{a_{m}})$$

And since $f$ is multiplicative and each of the $p_{i}$ are relatively prime,

$$= f(p_{1}^{a_{1}})f(p_{2}^{a_{2}})\cdots f(p_{m}^{a_{m}})$$

$$= \sum_{d|p_{1}^{a_{1}}}g(d)\sum_{d|p_{2}^{a_{2}}}g(d)\cdots\sum_{d|p_{m}^{a_{m}}}g(d)$$

$$= (1+a_{1}\cdot2^{1})(1+a_{2}\cdot2^{1})\cdots(1+a_{m}\cdot2^{1})$$

$$ = \prod_{k=1}^{m}(1+2a_{k}).$$

Answer (score 0):

You have proven that $g$ is multiplicative, but where does it say that $f$ is multiplicative? What is your justification for writing

$$f(p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{m}^{a_{m}}) = f(p_{1}^{a_{1}})f(p_{2}^{a_{2}})\cdots f(p_{m}^{a_{m}})?$$

I suggest you instead replace $f(p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{m}^{a_{m}})$ with the definition of $f$ using the sum and then use multiplicity of $g$.

Comment: The question mentions it as a hint, so I assumed it would be useful. But I'll try it your way.

Comment: Yeah I don't see that going anywhere because the divisors of $n$ aren't exactly easy to write down in closed form. For example the divisors of 36 are ${1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18, 36}$ and there's no "pattern" in writing $g(i)$ for each $i \elementof {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18, 36}$